# PowerShell Read-Host

Tags: powershell, user-interface

SO, in my PS script I am asking the user multiple questions.

example:

```
$username = Read-Host("What is your username?")
$password = Read-Host("What is your password?")
$monthName = Read-Host("Which month are you running this report for?")
$data = Read-Host("Enter the full path to the data file you would like to report?")
```

I know if I make a GUI I can ask all of these questions at once, however I have not made a GUI in PS before(although I am trying).

Is there any other way I can ask all of these questions at once, without building a GUI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest just using Primal Forms to create a gui. Its as easy as dragging and dropping windows, text boxes, buttons, ect. It generates the proper script based on what you designed and you just copy the code into PowerShell.

.. and it's FREE ! (The community edition, which is more than you'll need) .. just create an account 
http://www.sapien.com/software/communitytools#PrimalFormsCE

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If it is anything like visual studio it will definitely help me out. I am downloading it now, thanks!

Comment: @BigRabbit Yea it's exactly like that

Comment: @BigRabbit Read Here : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/24/create-a-simple-graphical-interface-for-a-powershell-script.aspx ... pretty much you look for the comment that says : `#TODO: Place custom script here`, but you can make functions and call them from the Events to keep your code neater

Comment: yeah I think I got it figured out I looked at a few examples. I appreciate the help thank you very much!